# Why isn't $\arctan \theta = \frac{\arcsin \theta}{ \arccos \theta}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Why is it that $\arctan \theta \neq \dfrac{\arcsin\theta}{\arccos\theta}$ ?

Thanks for your help in figuring this out.

Comment: Why *would* it be?

Comment: because $\tan(x y) \ne \tan(x) \tan(y)$ ?

Comment: More or less for the same reason as $\dfrac1{x+y}\neq\dfrac1x+\dfrac1y$. It would be a nice formula. Unfortunately, the mathematical world, just like the real world, is not that simple.

Comment: Any two real numbers differing by an integral multiple of $2\pi$ are regarded as determining the same angle, e.g. $\tfrac{\pi}{2}$ is the same angle as $\tfrac{5\pi}{2}$, and $\tfrac{\pi}{4}$ is the same angle as $\tfrac{9\pi}{4}$. But the operation of division (or for that matter, multiplication) gives different results when you add multiples of $2\pi$ to its arguments, e.g. $\tfrac{\pi}{2}/\tfrac{\pi}{4} = 2$, but $\tfrac{5\pi}{2}/\tfrac{9\pi}{4} = \tfrac{10}{9}$, So it isn't really possible to make sense of the idea of 'dividing' one angle by another, as is done on the RHS of your identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one thing,
the principal value of
arctan is from
$0$ to $\pi$ on Monday,
Wednesday, and Friday,
and from
$-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$
on Tuesday, Thursday, and
Saturday.

However
$\frac{\arcsin x}{\arccos x}$
is unbounded as
$x \to \pi/2$,
so this can not be a value
of $\arctan$.

Comment: Who does put the downvote?

Comment: Probably a heathen who wants to compute arctangents on Sunday.

Answer (score 2):

I hope the quite elementary figure below can help you.

[image]